# Substitution for 0.1Ω 2W metal film resistor?

Tags: resistors, components, repair, damage, replacement

I'm attempting to repair a Pure Sine Wave Inverter.

I need to replace a damaged 0.1Ω 2W metal film resistor. I found the part that should work on digitkey: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/yageo/MFR200FBF73-0R1/9136767
MFR#: MFR200FBF73-0R1

However, the min order qty is 5000. I looked on mouser and couldn't find it there. I only need one for the repair and probably some extra to keep around.

Anyone know of a different place i could search or for good substitution? I'm not certain as to the function of these resistors in this circuit. There are several of them in parallel with each other, all of the same value.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: A Digikey "view similar" search starting from the device you linked gives [this](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/yageo/FKN200JR-73-0R1/2812963) which has same size and looser tolerance, or [this](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/ohmite/12FR100E/1756764) which has same tolerance and rated power but smaller physical dimension. Take your pick.

Comment: Probably it is a current shunt for measuring input or output current to the inverter. Maybe you can find 0.2 Ohm resistors, 1 Watt, and use twice as many. Or use 2 percent or 5 percent tolerance resistors.

Comment: Thanks @nanofarad - I suppose I can always measure the resistance before installing it to see if its within tolerance.

Comment: @mkeith Ahh good call - these resistors are located near the front panel with the main voltage indicator. The user reported there was a spark and thinks water got into the inverter. However, the inverter was still working after the spark happened. It was until later that it failed. I also found several blown fuses. I wonder what the chain of events were that causes the unit to eventually fail.

Comment: @c4am95 If you're planning to measure, make sure your measurement device and technique are accurate to 1%. Kelvin sensing and precision current source/voltmeter will likely be crucial/

Comment: @nanofarad Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Those resistors being damaged suggests other problems that will need to be fixed first.

Comment: What @Kartman said  ^^^    For a resistor that size, I might expect them to be a bit "brown" from heat-related aging if it were the resistor that had just "gone bad".   The way that one looks, it was catastrophic.  Something else failed which caused that resistor to take too much heat too quickly.  Got a schematic?